# SQL Query Help - Subqueries/Embed Queries

Tags: sql, oracle

I am just starting learn SQL at work, but I am having trouble with subquerys. 
I am hoping for not just a Query, but an explanation of how to create subqueries.

Current SQL Query

```
SELECT to_char(P_DT, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mi:ss'), COUNT, LATENCY 
FROM latency ORDER BY P_DT
```

Returns

```
to_char(P_DT, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mi:ss'), COUNT, LATENCY
2012-04-20 03:42:00     83659   1m
2012-04-20 03:42:00 70305   2m
2012-04-20 03:42:00 105194  4m
2012-04-20 03:43:00 70277   1m
2012-04-20 03:43:00 0   2m
2012-04-20 03:43:00 0   4m
```

What I need

```
to_char(P_DT, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mi:ss'), COUNT.LATENCY='1m', COUNT.LATENCY='2m', COUNT.LATENCY='4m'
2012-04-20 03:42:00 83659       70305      105194
2012-04-20 03:43:00 70227       0          0
```

Thanks

Database has 3 columns: Timestamp, Count, Latency Type

```
Tmestamp = progressive timestamp for each min
Count = count, just a number
Latency Type = 1m, 2m or 4m
```

Each timestamp has a 1m, 2m, and 4m latency but these are all different rows.

I need to return one row that is
timestamp, count for 1m at timestamp, count for 2m at timestamp, count for 4m at timestamp

I can't change the database to instead of count1m column count2m column etc.

A different way of looking at it is merging these three queries into one

```
SELECT to_char(P_DT, \'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mi:ss\'), COUNT 
FROM LATENCY 
WHERE SOURCE_ID=\'2\' AND LATENCY = \'1m\' 
GROUP BY to_char(P_DT, \'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mi:ss\') 
ORDER BY to_char(P_DT, \'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mi:ss\')

SELECT to_char(P_DT, \'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mi:ss\'), COUNT 
FROM LATENCY 
WHERE SOURCE_ID=\'2\' AND LATENCY = \'2m\' 
GROUP BY to_char(P_DT, \'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mi:ss\') 
ORDER BY to_char(P_DT, \'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mi:ss\')

SELECT to_char(P_DT, \'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mi:ss\'), COUNT 
FROM LATENCY 
WHERE SOURCE_ID=\'2\' AND LATENCY = \'4m\' 
GROUP BY to_char(P_DT, \'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mi:ss\') 
ORDER BY to_char(P_DT, \'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mi:ss\')
```

Comment: If you explained what you need in a few more words, I'd have a chance to understand :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, this should do it:

```
SELECT  to_char(P_DT, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mi:ss'), 
        SUM(CASE WHEN LATENCY = '1m' THEN COUNT ELSE 0 END) AS LATENCY1m, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN LATENCY = '2m' THEN COUNT ELSE 0 END) AS LATENCY2m, 
        SUM(CASE WHEN LATENCY = '4m' THEN COUNT ELSE 0 END) AS LATENCY4m
FROM latency 
GROUP BY to_char(P_DT, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mi:ss')
ORDER BY to_char(P_DT, 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:mi:ss')
```

Comment: Error: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: What is 
SUM(CASE WHEN LATENCY = '1m' THEN LATENCY ELSE 0 END) AS
supposed to do?

Comment: @djc391 - Maybe it was the alias of the columns?, I really don' know why you got that error

Comment: OP Has a column called `[count]` which I think you should display rather then the `SUM` and `GROUP`ing....

Comment: @MatthewPK - You are right about the columns, I changed the `SUM` to reflect this, though I still think that the only way to do it is `GROUP`ing

Comment: Still having Error: FROM keyboard not found where expected

Comment: @djc391 - Then, I don't really know what is the problem. What RDBMS are you using anyway?, I'm assuming Oracle

Comment: @djc391 - Maybe the problem was with aliases I was using on the columns, try de updated query and see if it works